# Is there a timeline showing the various (known) religions and their birthdates?

Tags: religion

I'm trying to establish origins for the worlds major religions, but eager to research some minor ones as well. I am hoping to find a correlation between several religions based on the timetable of their origins. Many of the ancient civilizations just stole gods from earlier civilizations and I would like to have something I can reference that shows this.

I'm operating under the assumption that some historians have tracked and monitored religions as a meme and that I'm not the only one who would find such a timeline useful.

As for sects and denominations I would treat them each as their own religion for the purpose of the timeline I am searching for, but I would welcome even a timeline that didn't differentiate at this level.

Comment: There are a *ton* of religions out there. Would a sect or denomination count as another religion? What time period are we looking at? What area? Where do you draw the line between indigenous religions? How do you show major religions with no clear (or known) starting point?

Comment: He's probably just asking if there is something already constructed that more or less shows this information

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. I figured History.StackExchange would be the place to ask this kind of question as it's history related (heck, it's a timeline for pete's sake) and it's a definitive non-discussion oriented question. Either there is or there isn't a timeline that shows the emergence of the various religions as best as historians can agree upon.